# Confused on some MongoDB basics

Tags: mongodb

I am currently working on the 3rd lesson in the "learnyoumongo" tutorial and am currently confused on what process.argv has to do with the current tutorial.

The goal of the tutorial is to work with a database named 'learnyoumongo'.
Mongod is set to the default port 27017.
I need to use the 'parrots' collection to find all documents where 'age' is greater than the first argument passed to the script.

The solution to the challenge is below.

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var age = process.argv[2]

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/learnyoumongo'

mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err
  var parrots = db.collection('parrots')
  parrots.find({
    age: {
      $gt: +age
    }
  }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(docs)
    db.close()
  })
})
```

I am confused with line 2. We set the variable age to process.argv[2]. Yet when I attempt to console.log this, i receive null. Is it suppose to be null? Does process.argv get used a lot in Mongo?? Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process.argv property returns an array containing the command line arguments passed while launching nodejs process.

For example if your file name is index.js and you launch it like this :

node index.js 20

if will create an array :

```
argv[0] => /usr/local/bin/node
argv[1] => /path_to_node_folder/index.js
argv[2] => 20
```

Hence you are basically passing the age as a parameter in command prompt while launching node

In your case, you are passing age as the parameter which will then used internally for your logic. Hence to have a value of age in console log, pass it while launching the node file like :

```
node yourFile.js 10
```

where 10 is the age i have passed.

Comment: OOOOO it makes sense now! Thanks you!